# Exit batch script

Tags: batch-file, echo

I have batch script,I saved res.bat and run,but it is not Exit when finish run.Help me!!!

```
echo Set objShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" ) > %TEMP%\sp.vbs
echo Set objSystemEnv = objShell.Environment( "SYSTEM" ) >> %TEMP%\sp.vbs
echo objSystemEnv("Path") = objSystemEnv("Path") ^& ";ABCAA" >> %TEMP%\sp.vbs
cscript.exe /nologo %TEMP%\sp.vbs
del %TEMP%\sp.vbs
cls
```

Comment: Excuse me, I don't understand what your problem is. How do you run this Batch file? What happens then? What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: What do you mean by *"but it is not Exit when finish run"*? The script enters an endless loop? The command window does not exit? Is there more code that you are not showing?

Answer (score 3):

Try putting an `@exit` command at the end of the script.

Or you can try this script:

```
Dim objShell : Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Dim objSysEnv : Set objSysEnv = objShell.Environment("SYSTEM") 
objSysEnv("PATH") = objSysEnv("PATH") & ";ABCAA"
```

and save it as vbs. It will run with no window at all. Tested on my PC. I had to clean my path variable since I will not be using it :). It's not bat, but it,s working.

Comment: I have tried it in Windows XP SP3 and worked for me. It produces no window, but if you manually check the result in system path variable it should be added at the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

It the end of the code `@exit` WILL NOT WORK! Try doing just `exit` or maybe `close` or `stop`.